# GStreamer preview RTMP using xvimage

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, gst-launch

I want to preview RTMP using gstreamer xvimagesink. i can see the output if i use autovideosink like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtmpsrc location='rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/stream' ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink
```

but if i replace "autovideosink" with "xvimagesink" i get this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1773): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
Could not open display (null)
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`decodebin3`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/playback/decodebin3.html?gi-language=c) and [autovideosink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/autodetect/autovideosink.html?gi-language=c) are [auto-plugging](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/autoplugging.html?gi-language=c) GStreamer elements. It means that both elements are auto-selecting available and the most appropriate GStreamer plugins to demux/decode (decodebin3) and render video (autovideosink) from, in this case, live RTMP stream.

So it is very possible that, for example,

- `decodebin3` decodes video in format that `xvimagesink` cannot show on your platform/hardware and/or with your Gstreamer version,
- `xvimagesink` is not set properly on your platform and it is not related with available  display/monitor.

To find out more details about

- video format decoded by `decodebin3`
- video sink element "chosen" by `autovideosink`,

you can set higher (more detailed) debug level of GStreamer with, for example, `export GST_DEBUG=3`, rerun pipeline and inspect output.